# Find first div with specific class; starting from bottom

Tags: jquery, html

On my page I would like the find the first occurance of a div with a specific class but instead of going from top to bottom I would like to go from bottom to top.

Say I have the following HTML.

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="1" class="something special"></div>
   <div id="2" class="something"></div>
   <div id="3" class="something special"></div>
   <div id="4" class="something"></div>
   <div id="5" class="something special"></div>
   <div id="6" class="something"></div>
</div>
```

How would I write my Jquery to find the first occurance of class "special" from the bottom. So returning me the div with ID: 5?

Comment: Is there a difference between "last occurance" and "first occurance from the bottom"?

Comment: @lupz well no, not really. But wouldn't it be performance efficient to search from the bottom going up? Instead of looking through every single div untill it reaches the bottom? I was wondering if such functionality exists.

Comment: There would be a difference, but you're talking double-figure milliseconds. If you're using jQuery, then that kind of optimisation is completely moot.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Alright, if performance like that is so small it won't be a factor at all I will just be using the :last selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:last` selector to get the target element, then `prop()` to get its `id`:

```js
var id = $('.special:last').addClass('foo').prop('id');
console.log(id);
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="1" class="something special">something special</div>
  <div id="2" class="something">something</div>
  <div id="3" class="something special">something special</div>
  <div id="4" class="something">something</div>
  <div id="5" class="something special">something special</div>
  <div id="6" class="something">something</div>
</div>
```